# Programatically serialize objects into .NET resources during build

Tags: .net, .net-core, serialization, msbuild

I want to add a build step that programmatically generates a .resources file for a .NET project, based on some constant objects in the library.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is that I have one project that provides a class for which I want to have a concrete object saved as a resource in an external library in a way, that the external library's resources are generated at build time from a set of files that instantiate the class with some values, which is then bundled with the rest of the project.

I tried looking at MSBuild's documentation, but I'm not really at home in the dotnet ecosystem so I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for. Is there some module that'd let me do this without a custom MSBuild module, or do I need to write something myself?

Comment: Build steps are possible but tricky to set up - could your problem be solved by writing a Roslyn Source Generator that creates instantiation functions / methods into a custom class instead of using resources?

Comment: That could be a solution, as I said, I'm not really versed in dotnet, and implementing a build step to generate resources felt logical, but I'll go check out Roslyn and see what I can do.